# .htaccess but only from GET variable

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I am using wordpress and need to redirect wp-login?action=register to /registration/ page,

first i did

```
Redirect /wp-login.php http://www.class-world.com/register/
```

but then it also keeps redirecting logout wp-login.php?action=logout so cant logout at all.

My question is how to only redirect action=register, instead of whole wp-login.php

I tried with following:

RewriteRule ^/wp-login.php\?action=register$ /register/

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/wp-login.php\?action=register$ /register/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=register
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ /register/ [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting now page not found error, but its redirecting fine.

Comment: Just a question : you want that when you access to /registration/, you see the wp-login.php?action=register page ?

Comment: no,i need redirect from wp-login.php?action=register  to /registration/

Comment: +1 This answer is correct and does what OP asks for. However WP system wouldn't like `/register` URL and even if you add an internal forward it will still throw 404.

Comment: so you say its impossible ? I have /register/ url thats working, but i need to redirect also from that default wp-login?action=register.

Comment: It's possible only if you rewrite the /registrer/ url to an existant folder.

Comment: And if my answer could help you, you can validate it.